# How to design RESTful URLs for n-m relation?

Tags: java, restful-url

I have two objects, user and role. They are connected n:m with the UserRole table.

How should I design the url pattern to get the information if one user has a specific role (e.G. "ADMIN")

In restful service, I want to have one method to know if one user has "ADMIN" role. how can I design the URL pattern to fetch it.

```
/rest/users/{userId}/roles?admin=true
```

or

```
/rest/userroles/{userId}?admin=true
```

or use OData protocol

```
/rest/userroles/filter=UserId eq userId and roleId eq 'Admin'
```

any other suggestions?

after thinking a while, I think maybe below one is good

/rest/users/{userId}/roles/{roleName} . means if want to verify the user has Admin role, then pass

/rest/users/XXXX/roles/admin. if has, return true, otherwise throw notfoundexception.

any opinions?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am not quite sure if we can use "validateRole" this kind of method in URL based on RESTFUL definition.

Comment: What's wrong with GETing all the roles and having the UI figure out if Admin is among them? What does this hypothetical URL return? A body containing true or false? That's overkill for a web API.

Comment: emm. for this case, I think use the /rest/users/{userId}/roles/{roleName} is proper solution. for returning body, i think can just use status code, if return 200 means this user has admin role, 404 means no. no need true/false.